# Blit a rectangle at by coordinate

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, pygame-surface

In Pygame and Python 2.7, how can I blit a rectangle at certain point represented by a set of coordinates?

I know I can use this:

```
screen.blit(img.image, img.rect.topleft)
```

But I want the rectangle to be at a precise point on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need topleft corner of rectangle in point `(34,57)` you can do

```
screen.blit(img.image, (34,57) )
```

or this

```
img.rect.topleft = (34,57)

screen.blit(img.image, img.rect)
```

or this

```
img.rect.x = 34
img.rect.y = 57

screen.blit(img.image, img.rect)
```

If you need center of rectange in point `(34,57)`

```
img.rect.center = (34,57)

screen.blit(img.image, img.rect)
```

If you need rectangle in center of the screen:
(especially useful if you need to show text (ex. "PAUSE") in center of the screen, or text in center of rectangle to create button)

```
img.rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

screen.blit(img.image, img.rect)
```

If you need rectangle touching right border of the screen:

```
img.rect.right = screen.get_rect().right

screen.blit(img.image, img.rect)
```

If you need rectangle in bottom left corner of the screen:

```
img.rect.bottomleft = screen.get_rect().bottomleft

screen.blit(img.image, img.rect)
```

And you have more - see [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

```
x,y
top, left, bottom, right
topleft, bottomleft, topright, bottomright
midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
center, centerx, centery
```

Using above element it doesn't change `width` and `height`.
If you change `x` (or other value) then you automaticly get new value of `left`, `right` and others.

**BTW:** As you see you can use `img.rect` as argument in `blit()`

**BTW:** You can also do this: (for example in `__init__`):

```
img.rect = img.image.get_rect(center=screen.get_rect().center)
```

to center object on screen

**BTW:** You can use it also to blit image/`Surface` on other `Surface` at a precise point. You can put text in center of some surface (for example: button) and then that surface put in bottomright corner of the screen

Comment: BTW, how can I adjust the size of the rect? I tried pygame.rect.inflate(x,y), but it still showed the original size  :(

Comment: `print img.rect.size` to see what you get. But changing rectangle you can't change image size - To resize image you have to use [pygame.transform](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html) on `img.image`. And after image resize you have to user `img.rect.size = img.image.get_rect().size` to have correct `img.image` size in `img.rect`.

Comment: ps. `inflate(x,y)` give you new rectanlge and doesn't change oryginal. `new_rect = img.rect.inflate(x,y)`. Use `inflate_ip` to resize oryginal rectangle - it is called modification `in-place`.

Comment: See all pages in [PyGame Doc](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) and at least read names of classes and functions - it give you some orientation in PyGame.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
screen.blit(img.image, img.rect.topleft)
```

will put the image at (0, 0) since the rect has been obtained from an image that has not yet been drawn to the display surface. If you want to draw at a specific coordinate simply do this:

```
screen.blit(image, (x, y))     #x and y are the respective position coordinates
```